# Squaring elements of matrix affecting rank

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have column vectors $u_1,...,u_n$ forming the matrix $U$. Now these vectors are independent for the sake we can also assume that that they are mutually orthogonal. I.e. $U$ has full rank. If I square each entry of U, will the resulting matrix be still full rank any ideas or counter examples?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Counterexample:

$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1& 1\\ 1 &-1
\end{array}\right)
$$

Comment: There should be similar counterexamples for all dimensions $n$.

Comment: There are. In fact, $n \times n$ binary (1, -1) matrices of full rank can be constructed for any $n$ (e.g., cyclic permutations of the vector $[-1, 1, 1, \ldots, 1]$ work for any $n>2$). Their element-wise square is always rank-one.